# How to sample pairs in order to create a significant result

Tags: sampling, biostatistics

I develop a similarity function for genes in general. I would like to find the correlation of the similarity values of the developed function to a ground truth. For the ground truth, I use a model organism and I have 2000 genes with distinct Gene Ontology (GO) terms. For a pair of genes I can find the similarity of the two genes based on the GO terms for example using [GAPGOM](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GAPGOM/inst/doc/GAPGOM.html#topoicsim) tool. However as the genes are too many the possible number of pairs (2000 choose 2) is too big (millions) so I can't wait calculating the GAPGOM similarity for all pairs.

Thus, I would like your advice on how to sample pairs and then calculate the GAPGOM similarity but still leaving the result significant.

I have already asked in [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/405786/#406075).

Comment: is it really too much to calculate 1998000 similarity scores? also, this is easy to be parallelized.

Comment: the issue is that I use the similarity function provided by GAPGOM R package so it not on my hand the computation time neither the parallelization. Of course, if I do my own similarity function then I can try to do something more quick/less detailed and I can also parallelize but I thought GAPGOM as the last GO similarity research paper is a much better method than a baseline (quick) similarity function.

Comment: Hm, I see. My idea would be to calculate your score for all pairs (which is hopefully faster than GAPCOM), put the scores into brackets (like by deciles) and calculate the GAPCOM scores for some chosen representatives of the decile-brackets and check if there's significant differences within these brackets. It's not exhaustive but should give you a first impression if the scores align.

Comment: Edgar thank you very much.. when I finalize my approach, I will post it to help anyone else..